# How do I prove that transactionsroot is correct?

Tags: transactions, ethash

I have this block on Ropsten,

```
'difficulty': 3963642329, 
'extraData': '0xd88301080f846765746888676f312e31302e31856c696e7578'), 
'gasLimit': 8000000, 
'gasUsed': 7987824, 
'hash': '0x47b8f62c1400dae65105d2f8e03824bfc58481c0b32f45788ad3378fbc05e9f6', 
'logsBloom': '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', 
'miner': '0x6A9ECfa04e99726eC105517AC7ae1aba550BeA6c', 
'mixHash': '0x0c0026c706351083c0a913e084dee16ca133b813baa6a174e4fb179d9f2ecc52', 
'nonce': '0xf245822d3412da7f', 
'number': 4156209, 
'parentHash': '0xad22d4d8f0e94032cb32e86027e0a5533d945ed95088264e91dd71e4fbaebeda', 
'receiptsRoot': '0xeb1e644436f93be8a9938dfe598cb7fd729f9d201b6f7c0695bee883b3ea6a5b', 
'sha3Uncles': '0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347', 
'size': 27324, 'stateRoot': '0x43e3325393fbc583a5a0b56e98073fb81e82d992b52406a79d662b690a4d2753', 
'timestamp': 1538483791, 
'totalDifficulty': 11844984547350924, 
'transactions': [.......], 
'transactionsRoot': '0x40c339f7715932ec591d8c0c588bacfaed9bddc7519a1e6e87cf45be639de810', 'uncles': []
```

and now I can recreate the transactionsRoot with a trie, but how do I prove that the transactionsRoot is acualy the txRoot of that block?

My main question is: Is the txRoot part of the blockHash? and if so, how to obtain the blockhash?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: block's hash is 0x47b8f62c1400dae65105d2f8e03824bfc58481c0b32f45788ad3378fbc05e9f6 , 5th field from the top

Comment: Yeah :) Thank you.... Actually I am trying to prove that the txroot belongs to this hash. I mean the blockhash or txroot could have been tampered with.

Comment: the only way to prove is to recalculate the data (by calling Hash() function) yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in Python:

```
class MyBlockHeader(rlp.Serializable):
    fields = [
        ('parentHash', hash32),
        ('sha3Uncles', hash32),
        ('miner', address),
        ('stateRoot', trie_root),
        ('transactionsRoot', trie_root),
        ('receiptsRoot', trie_root),
        ('logsBloom', int256),
        ('difficulty', big_endian_int),
        ('number', big_endian_int),
        ('gasLimit', big_endian_int),
        ('gasUsed', big_endian_int),
        ('timestamp', big_endian_int),
        ('extraData', binary),
        ('mixHash', binary),
        ('nonce', Binary(8, allow_empty=True))
    ]

    def hash(self) -> bytes:
        '''use the rlp and hash to recalculate the blockhash'''
        return keccak(rlp.encode(self))
```

and there the hash() includes the tx-root. So then there is the Proof that the txroot is in the Block.